# How to create a set of deep objects

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a collection of objects, A.

```
class A{  
     String name;
     Collection<B> listOfB;
}

class B {
     String address;
     String phone;
     int age;
}
```

I want to create new collection of A objects, where 2 objects have the same name, address, and phone. Can anyone tell me if this is the best way to do this?

I create a map of Key-A. The key would be as follows:

```
Key {
String name;
String address;
String phone;
}
```

I only as A objects to the list if their corresponding Key is not present.

Comment: Your question is highly confusing. Can you please rephrase ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you want a map `Map<Key, A>`. The important thing is that you define equality and the hash code (in case you want a hash map) for the `Key`:

```
class Key {
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;

    @Override // override in Object
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if(!other instanceof Key) return false;
        Key otherKey = (Key) other;
        return name.equals(otherKey.name) && address.equals(otherKey.address) && phone.equals(otherKey.phone); // check for null if fields can be null
    }

    @Override // override in Object
    public int hashCode() {
        return name.hashCode() ^ address.hashCode() ^ phone.hashCode(); // or something along those lines
    }
 }
```

Also good idea to create a constructor for the `Key` and make the fields `private` and `final`.

I'm not sure how this key is derived though. Ideally, the `Key` would somehow be derived from `A`, or - even better - `A` would have a `hashCode` and `equals` method so you do not need a map but you can use a `Set`. This really depends on the data you want to model though and your question is not clear enough to give a specific recommendation.

Answer (score -1):

First, implement `hascode` and `equals` method in class B.
In `equals` method return `true` when name,phone and adress are the same.

Second time, create your map like this=

```
HashMap<B,A> myMap;
```

A key in a map is always unique.

Comment: He wants a dedicated `Key` class.

Comment: @heyya99: In that case though, the question is not specific enough. It really matters how the `Key` is defined for any `A`.